# AngularJs textbox validation, restricting characters with regex negative lookahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

Using angular js here:

I have a textbox where I want to apply certain regex and prevent the user with certain characters. Here is what I want:

- Prevent user to start and end with an underscore.
- No Special chars allowed
- Characters and numbers are allowed and can start or end with either
- Only underscore is allowed in between chars/digits and again not at
  the start or end.
- Should not have consecutive underscore.

Below is code what I have:

TextBox:

```
 <input type="text" name="uname" ng-model="uname" required class="form-
  control input-medium" placeholder="Enter  name..." maxlength="20" restrict-
  field="alpha-numeric" ng-trim="false" />
```

Directive:

```
.directive("restrictField", function() {
return {
  require: "ngModel",
  restrict: "A",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    var regReplace,
      preset = {
        "alphanumeric-spl": "\\w_./s/g",
        "alphanumeric-underscore": "\\w_",
        "numeric": "0-9",
        "alpha-numeric": "\\w"           
      },
      filter = preset[attrs.restrictField] || attrs.restrictField;

    ctrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
      regReplace = new RegExp('[^' + filter + ']', 'ig');

      if (inputValue == undefined) return "";
      cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(regReplace, "");
      if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
        ctrl.$render();
      }
      return cleanInputValue;
    });
  }
   };
  });
```

While the above works for the simple patterns that I have used in my directives but does not work for the pattern which I have described above. From my other post I have got the pattern to use for regex negative lookahead as below:

```
^(?!_)(?!.*_$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$
```

But this does not work if I try to include it in my directive.

Here is my sample Codepen that I have created:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LJBbQd

How can I apply the above regex. If not this, is there a workaround or any other approach to restrict my textbox with this regex.

Thanks

Comment: In that previous question, I also suggested another approach and `/^_+|_+$|_+(?=_)|\W+/g` to remove `_`s where they are redundant. As I also commented, you cannot use a simple negated character class since you need to remove text in different *contexts*, something a negated character class itself cannot do), you will have to add more programming logic or use another approach to sanitizing input.

Comment: With the regex you posted above I tried to use: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wExgvK It allows all spl chars and does not allows underscore at all. Can you provide an example of what other logic or other approach do I have to use if I cant use the negated class.

Comment: Actually, all that works, look [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXBrZK). If the `restrict-field="alphanumeric-underscore"`, you cannot enter `_` that is at the start and end of the string (and several `_` on end), but if you type `12` you may add `_` in between `1` and `2`. Again, there is a problem with your approach.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not sure what am I doing wrong here but I cannot get your codepen to work. I typed 1 after that it does not allows me to type an underscore at all. I even tried with alphabet. Can you check pls? I am using chrome browser .

Comment: That is what I wrote about. You may type `12` and then add `_` in between `1` and `2`. Else, if you remove `_+$|` from the pattern, you will "allow" `_` at the end.

Comment: I understand now but not exactly what I am looking for. Would it be possible to not use the directive itself. And may be use some textbox event like keyup and then apply regex there. Would it work that way?

Comment: So,  have you made up your mind on what behavior you need?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to allow a `_` at the end, and use an HTML5 pattern attribute with a regex that requires the last char to be any char but a `_` with `pattern=".*[^_]"`. If you need to allow an empty string, use `pattern="(?:.*[^_])?"`.

```js
var app = angular
  .module("myApp", ["ui.bootstrap"])
  .directive("restrictField", function() {
    return {
      require: "ngModel",
      restrict: "A",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        var regReplace,
          preset = {
            'alphanumeric-spl': '[^\\w\\s./]+', // Removes all but alnum, _ . / whitespaces
            'alphanumeric-underscore': '^_+|_+(?=_)|\\W+', // Removes all _ at start and all _ before a _ and all but alnum and _
            'numeric': '[^0-9]+', // Removes all but digits
            'alpha-numeric': '[\\W_]+' // Removes all but alnum
          },
          filter = preset[attrs.restrictField] || attrs.restrictField;

        ctrl.$parsers.push(function(inputValue) {
          console.log(filter);
          regReplace = RegExp(filter, 'ig');

          if (inputValue == undefined) return "";
          cleanInputValue = inputValue.replace(regReplace, "");
          if (cleanInputValue != inputValue) {
            ctrl.$setViewValue(cleanInputValue);
            ctrl.$render();
          }
          return cleanInputValue;
        });
      }
    };
  });

// Define the `appController` controller on the `ReportsMockUpsApp` module
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px
}

input:valid {
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid #dadadada;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

input:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: .glowing-border:focus;
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <label>Wow</label>
    <input type="text" pattern=".*[^_]" name="uname" ng-model="uname" required class="form-control input-medium" placeholder="Enter  name..." maxlength="20" restrict-field="alphanumeric-underscore" ng-trim="false" />


  </div>
</div>
```